# How to handle QR Code Generation for Login Puporses on a dummy site?

Tags: authentication, qr-code, password-manager

I'm looking to create an application for a project using flutter for mobile devices which will act as a password manager with a QR scanner which will enable seamless logins, similarly to how Steam Guard, and DIscord works.

Essentially the user will have their username and password stored in profiles, they will select a profile and then have an option to launch the QR scanner. Then on the site they are looking to login to (on another device) they will be presented with a QR code, scanning this QR code with the correct password profile will log them in.

The QR code generation I'm thinking will either take place via being hard coded on a dummy site, or I may look into developing an API for it and then implementing the API on the dummy site.

I'm in the very early stages and need to figure out a hosting so just wanted to know what technologies are likely to be needed for the QR generation and authentication on the dummy site?

Still in the planning stages so haven't tried implementing anything yet? Just looking for a starting point.